# Using custom value instead User.Identity.Name on LoginPartial view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Usual _LoginPartial.cshtml has next:

```
Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
```

I want to use custom field from LoginModel model instead User.Identity.Name.
How can I do that?

Or is it possible to set to User.Identity.Name something else than login?

Comment: set `User.Identity.Name` inside any `model property say myprop` in controller and then use `@Model.myprop` inside `actionlink`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For something global, like your layout, you should be using a child action, if you aren't already. Trying something like populating a `ViewBag` variable for each view individually is only going to result in failure, as you'll inevitably forget, or some new developer won't know to do so.

With a child action, you can pass whatever you like as a model to your partial view, which gives you the ability to actually look up your user from your persistent storage and use whatever properties you like on it.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult LoginPartial()
{
    // ASP.NET Identity
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    // Membership
    // var user = db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.UserName == User.Identity.Name);

    return PartialView("_LoginPartial", user);
}
```

Then in your your partial view, for Identity:

```
@model Namespace.To.ApplicationUser
```

Or, with Membership

```
@model Namespace.To.UserProfile
```

And, proceed to reference whatever properties off the user instance you like.

To call the child action in your layout:

```
@Html.Action("LoginPartial", "Account")
```

*(I've assumed that you've place the child action in your `AccountController`, which seems like the most logical place)*

Comment: +1 Great solution! I'm using this approach to display number of outstanding orders on the left side menu. Thanks Chris.

Comment: This make an HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found or better called  RequestFilteringModule overflow when user is not authenticated, not sure why, but seem that Login(string returnUrl) is called in a deep loop until until limit is reach

Comment: @CesarRomeroo: Ensure that the child action is either marked with `[AllowAnonymous]` or is in a controller that is not decorated with `[Authorize]`. Otherwise, the child action itself will require authorization, and if it's part of the layout, trying to load the sign in page to authorize will create a redirect loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ViewBag for passing information from Controller action to view. so you can create a base controller, which inherits from Controller, in the base controller you set the ViewBag in OnActionExecuting. And all other controllers can be inherited from Base Controller.

Then you can use Viewbag in the Layout or in any other partialview.

Comment: While this approach will work just fine, it's recommended to use child actions in these situations. If you're relying on a base controller to feed the layout a particular piece of data it needs, then all your controllers for all time must inherit from that base. If you forget, or a new developer comes along that doesn't know he/she needs to inherit from this base, then things get jacked up, with no obvious reason why.